# What's happening to my jQuery object when I pass it to a function as a parameter?

Tags: jquery

So the issue I'm having is that the function findNextSlide is returning undefined. I've logged everything every step of the way, it all seems to be working as expected when logged. I've debugged in the browser using breakpoints as well and can't tell what's causing it to return undefined.

All of this is being called on the click of a thumbnail image, which is the `<a>` with a class of `'.icon'`.  I'm checking to see if the parent of the next thumbnail image in the DOM is display:none, and if it is I'm setting the next slide to the one following the hidden image, and then calling the findNextSlide function again, just to make sure the image after that isn't also hidden, and then getting the underlying URL for that slide and returning it.

Maybe I have some fundamental misunderstanding with jQuery. When I log "$currentSlide" before it gets passed into the function, it logs as a jQuery object, but when I log it right after it's passed into the findNextSlide function, it logs as [Object object].

```js
var $currentSlide = $(this).parent();

function isSlideHidden(nextSlide) {
  return (nextSlide.css("display") === 'none')
}

function findNextSlide(currentSlide) {
  var $nextSlide = currentSlide.next().next();

  if (isSlideHidden($nextSlide)) {            
    var $newSlide = $nextSlide.next().next();

    findNextSlide($newSlide);
   }
   else {
     var $nextSlideUrl = $nextSlide.children('.icon').attr('href')
   }

   return $nextSlideUrl;
}
```

```html
<section class="work__grid clearfix wrapper" style="position: relative; height: 3285px;">
    <article class="grid__sizer"></article>
    <article class="grid__item  b2b featured marketing-communications  " style="background-image: url(&quot;//localhost:3000/app/uploads/2017/04/Square-Tiles_Verity_marketing.jpg&quot;); position: absolute; left: 1.33333%; top: 0px;">
        <a href="//localhost:3000/project/verity-2/" class="icon">
            <section class="grid__caption">
                <h3 class="grid__title">Verity</h3>
                <p class="grid__copy">Guiding&nbsp;healthcare providers and patients through&nbsp;340B saving and compliance</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </article>

    <section class="grid__item mobile__case-copy" style="background: none; position: absolute; display: none;">
        <h3 class="grid__title">Verity</h3>
        <p class="grid__copy">Guiding&nbsp;healthcare providers and patients through&nbsp;340B saving and compliance</p>
    </section>

    <article class="grid__item grid__item--wide consumer digital-experience featured leisure  " style="background-image: url(&quot;//localhost:3000/app/uploads/2018/01/2-Wide-Tiles_JuicyCafe.jpg&quot;); position: absolute; left: 33.8333%; top: 0px;">
        <a href="//localhost:3000/project/juicy-cafe/" class="icon">
            <section class="grid__caption">
                <h3 class="grid__title">Juicy Café</h3>
                <p class="grid__copy">Fueling the body and soul</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </article>

    <section class="grid__item mobile__case-copy" style="background: none; position: absolute; display: none;">
        <h3 class="grid__title">Juicy Café</h3>
        <p class="grid__copy">Fueling the body and soul</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your code is sort of unreadbale.

Comment: How is `findNextSlide` called? Missing a lot of code here.

Comment: Please take some time to create a [mcve] of the issue. You have a lot of code here that has nothing to do with your question that is making it hard to see the forest for the trees. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to construct a runnable example here on the site.